# How to load a .net MAUI solution on Visual Studio For Mac 2022 without installing Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, .net-6.0, visual-studio-mac, .net-maui, visual-studio-mac-2022

I've created a .net MAUI solution on the Mac via the command line:

`dotnet new maui -n "MyApp"`

When I open this via Visual Studio For Mac 2022, it errors out because Xamarin.Android is not installed.

I'm not interested in supporting Android at this point, and the download for Xamarin.Android is large. Is there any way to load the solution without installing Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Did you try removing net6.0-android from the TargetFramework in the csproj file?

Comment: @MattWard - Ah, that's probably it. I installed the Android SDK in the meantime - but good to know this setting. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.